# Prove that, when $N$ is a normal subgroup, $(gN)^a=(g^a)N$ for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, intuition, normal-subgroups

> Prove that, when $N$ is a normal subgroup, $(gN)^a=(g^a)N$ for all $a\in \mathbb{Z}$.

My attempt:

I know that if $b$ belongs to $H$ then

$$bH= H\tag{1}.$$

Also, $(ge)^a$ belongs to $(gN)^a$; therefore $(g^a)N=(gN)^a$ by $(1)$.

Is my attempt correct? Can someone suggest the intuition behind this?

Comment: The use of the € symbol is very creative... but you'd better learn how to type the formulas. For your question, you probably should say that $N$ is a normal subgroup.

Comment: Do you have that $(gN)(g’N) = (gg’N)$? If so then induction may help.

Comment: My guess is that it has something to do with $gNg^{-1}=N$ for all $g$ in the group that $N$ is normal in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Coset to a power](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170379/coset-to-a-power)

Answer (score 1):

This question is most naturally answered in the quotient group $G/N$, whose elements are of the form $gN$, for $g\in G$. This is allowed since $N$ is normal, and thus "quotientable".

Suppose $N$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$. The statement of the question is trivially true if $g\in N$, since in $G/N$, $gN=N\iff g\in N$.

If $g\not\in N$, then by the definition of products in $G/N$, 
$$(gN)^2=(gN)(gN)=g^2N$$
From there, you can use induction on the exponent to prove what you asked for.

Comment: I do get it .. but can you tell me whether my attempt is right or wrong ? bH=H is a property that was given in my textbook ..

Comment: As I said, $bH=H$ is only true if $b\in H$. You implicitly used the definition of products in $G/N$, which is good. I would just mention that for completeness, but otherwise it seems fine.